# Adding host attribute to generated DOM elements

Tags: javascript, d3.js, angular

I am trying to integrate d3 and angular2 alpha.37 (started from [here](https://github.com/gdi2290/ng-vegas-angular2-d3)).  The problem I am currently having is that the generated DOM elements don't get the attributes used in the emulated styling view encapsulation, and so I can't style them without setting the view encapsulation for the element to None (or Native, but I would rather use emulated).

I managed to programmatically extract the required attribute from an element inside the component [1], and then add it to the generated elements[2], which does work, but this is clearly incredibly hacky:

```
import {Component, View, Attribute, ElementRef, LifecycleEvent} from 'angular2/angular2';

import d3 from 'd3';

@Component({
  selector:   'bar-graph',
  properties: [ 'data' ]
})
@View({
  template: '<div class="chart"></div>',
  styles: [`.chart {
    background: #eee;
    padding: 3px;
  }

  div.bar {
    width: 0;
    transition: all 1s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-out;
  }

  div.bar {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
    background-color: steelblue;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 3px;
    margin: 5px;
    color: white;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #666;
  }`]
})
export class BarGraph implements LifecycleEvent.OnChanges {
  data: Array<number>;
  divs: any;
  constructor(elementRef: ElementRef, @Attribute('width') width: string, @Attribute('height') height: string) {


    var el:any    = elementRef.nativeElement;
    var graph:any = d3.select(el);

    this.hostAttr = graph[0][0].children[0].attributes[1].name; //hack here [1]

    this.divs = graph.
      select('div.chart').
      style({
        'width':  width  + 'px',
        'height': height + 'px',
      }).
      selectAll('div.bar');

  }

  render(newValue) {
    if (!newValue) return;

    this.divs.data(newValue)
        .enter().append('div')
          .classed('bar', true)
          .attr(this.hostAttr, true) //add the attribute here [2]
          .style('width', d => d + '%')
          .text(d => d + '%');

  }

  onChanges() {
    this.render(this.data);
  }

}
```

Is there a recommended way to deal with this sort of thing (or should I stop tinkering with the DOM outside of Angular2)?

Comment: If you want an answer, you'll have at least to upgrade to beta.0, at least.

Comment: @EricMartinez Same problem on beta.7.

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer (yet), but maybe some useful information that can help in finding a solution:

- The issue still exists in beta.8. Setting view encapsulation to `None` and using global styles was the only solution that I could get to work. Using `Native` seemed to result in no elements being added to the DOM at all, but I'd have to do some more tests to figure out the cause.
- The hack proposed by OP works, and could be refactored into a reasonable solution, at least in my opinion.
- In the specific case of `d3.js`, things get even more tricky when introducing elements that are created internally by the library, e.g. through the methods in the `d3.svg` namespace. Undoubtedly a workaround for that could be found as well.
- I believe that the issue is larger than `d3` however. There are plenty of libraries out there that have their own DOM generation/manipulation mechanisms, and it is not unrealistic to think that a portion of those will at some point be integrated in some or other `angular2` application. In that sense, it's surprising that the issue does not seem to have come up yet (or maybe my Google-fu is particularly weak this week).

In terms of solutions, these are the two approaches that I'm currently considering in case no one comes up with something nicer:

1. Implement some sort of post-processor that walks a partial DOM tree and sets the style scope attributes. Maybe as a directive?
2. Try to decorate the renderer, as hinted [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4973).